# $f$ analytic over $D$ and $f(x_n)=0$ then $f$ is identical to zero in $D$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am struggling with this problem:

> Suppose that $f$ is analytic over a region $D$ and that $f\left(x_k\right)=0$ in a sequence $\left(x_k \neq w\right)$ that has limit $w \in D $, then $f$ is identical to zero in $D$.

I'm not sure how to prove it, I think I don't have enough information to solve it, I mean I have only the basic definitions:

1. $D$ is a region, then it is a connected open set.
2. $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k =w$ but $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\neq x_k$, obviously avoiding $x_k=0$.
3. I need to prove $f\equiv 0$.

What do you think could be the an appropriate approach to resolved? This is a problem based on Complex Analysis, I have already finished the integral and series sections, but I don't find anything could help.

Comment: This is called the Identity Theorem and every book on Complex Analysis has  a proof.

Comment: You may prove that the Taylor coefficient $a_n$ are all zero where $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}a_n(z-w)^n$ is the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $z=w$.